# How to enable "email" field in iOS Stripe UI?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe UI in my iOS application. But when I presenting view controller for adding it asks only card info without email field. How I can enable this field at Stripe UI?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks, but previous answer resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Hi to solve your problem you should set property of the `SMS Autofill` to `false`. And you going to receive email field on the Stripe UI.

```
let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.sharedConfiguration()
config.smsAutofillDisabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

The SMS autofill feature was removed in v11.0, so the `STPAddCardViewController` no longer has an email field.